# Modifying std::set element by iterator: why is my code not compiling?

Tags: c++, compilation

**Updated**

This is the method that gives me trouble:

```
void A::normalizeUrls()
{
    for (set<CUrl>::iterator it = _references.begin(); it != _references.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->isValid())
        {
            it->normalize().makeFull(_baseUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are CUrl::normalize and CUrl::makeFull

```
CUrl& makeFull (CUrl&)
{
    return *this;
}
CUrl& CUrl::normalize()
{
    return *this;
}
```

The errors are: `CUrl::normalize' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CUrl' to 'CUrl &'`

`left of '.makeFull' must have class/struct/union`

Why is that so, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Errors or it didn't happen.

Comment: If you are using GCC (i.e. `g++`) to compile ypur code, you should pass `-Wall` to the compiler, and improve your code till you get no more warnings. You didn't tell use about the error reported by the compiler.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: VC2010. Did enable Wall, thanks for the hint. However, 3rdparty headers make it impossible. My default warn lvl is 3 out of 4.

Comment: The error points you to a totally different function to the one you posted.

Comment: @DeadMG: seems like I've messed the code a bit, now looks OK.

Comment: @Violet: No, no it doesn't. The error points to the implementation of CUrl::normalize, which is not posted.

Comment: A variation of the problem: `CUrl& curl_ref = it->normalize(); CUrl& curl_ref1 = it->makeFull(_baseUrl);` gives me the same `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CUrl' to 'CUrl &'` for both calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, the members of a set are `const` (immutable), so you cannot call non-const member functions on them.

If that was allowed, you might change their values and invalidate the ordering of the set.

Comment: Yep, I've just figured that out today. I would expect the container to reorder upon each non-const operation.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` will drop references.  I don't know if `auto&` works, but if not you'll have to specify `CUrl&` explicitly.

Comment: Didn't know about auto dropping refs, thanks. However, the original code was: `it->normalize().makeFull();`, and the errors are: `CUrl::normalize' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CUrl' to 'CUrl &'`, `left of '.makeFull' must have class/struct/union`

Comment: For that, see bithead61's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `_references.begin()` call is returning a const_iterator instead of a regular iterator.  Is the `_references` variable a const reference to the set?

It's definitely a problem with the *const* status of the iterator, though.  The following code compiles:

```
if (it->isValid())
{
    CUrl &ref = const_cast<CUrl&>(*it);
    ref.normalize().makeFull(_baseUrl);
}
```

Comment: I have the same impression. But no, it's a private class member: `std::set<CUrl> _references;`